# How do i change the url of wordpress search results?

Tags: wordpress

by default wordpress search results go to sitename.com/?s=terms but i would like it be changes to sitename.com/search/?s=terms

I have tried using the

```
fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
  if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
    exit();
  } 
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

This get close as now when you do search it goes to search/searchterm but does not have the ?s= in the url

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can change the rule in .htaccess

Add the following on the line after "RewriteBase /":

```
RewriteRule ^?s=(.*)$ search/?s=$1
```

See reference here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-default-search-string-s-to-permalink-structure

Comment: adding home_url( "/search/?s=" ) to the code does not make it work.  Where do you want me too the add the get_option around the search box in the header code or in functions.php where I added the code?

Comment: The rewrite crashes the site

Comment: RewriteRule does not match the query string at all, just the request URI. To match the query string you need to use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}. But even with those changes, these settings seem to do the opposite of what the OP was asking.